# Htaccess disallow inside directory

Tags: .htaccess

i have a directory with .htaccess with deny

```
deny from all
```

and inside that directory there is another directory with .htaccess like this:

```
<Directory "/dir1/dir2">
    Options All               
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How can i deny the access to second directory with htaccess on first directory?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: If possible use the real server configuration for such rules instead of `.htaccess` style files. Those files are hard to debug, notoriously error prone and really slow the server down.

Comment: Where i can find this feature (cpanel) ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about cpanel. My comment was meant as a general hint. If this is not your own server then it might be you have no access to the real server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files *>
deny from all
</Files>
```

did the job :)